# string to encode in CodePage 857

Tags: java

I need a function that can print Turkish characters.

```
public String convert(String input) {
    String output = new String(s.getBytes(input), "CodePage-857");
    return output;
}
```

Is there anyone out there can show me how to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: How about this: [Converting Between Strings Unicode and Other Character Set Encodings](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.nio.charset/ConvertChar.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I achieved it.

```
System.Text.Encoding CP857 = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(857);
return CP857.GetBytes("Text goes here");
```

Answer (score 0):

Java strings are UTF-16 by default which includes the Turkish character set. You can display the strings in UTF-8, UTF-16, or ISO-8859-3.

What view technology are you working with? It's probably configured for ISO-8859-1, which doesn't support Turkish.

Comment: Windows code pages are discussed here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page

Answer (score -2):

Java strings are always stored as UTF-16 therefore it wont help to create a new string from your input string. If you wan to print a string in a different encoding then you will need to address that on the actual displaying, e.g.: if you want to display it in a JSP page then the JSP page's encoding must be set to CodePage-857

Comment: Java internal representation is UTF-16 as discussed here: http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/basic/intl/faq.jsp#recommended-charset

Comment: @stark I meant UTF-16, but it doesn't invalidate the point of my answer :).